# how to do Transformation in vtklinewidget

Tags: c++, 3d, transformation, vtk, euler-angles

I am trying to draw a line using sensor coordinates and orientation angles. The one end of the line is sensor current location and i want to find the other end with same orientation as the current point. to achieve this i created a rotation matrix and multiplied it with the point that i want to rotate.

The line rotation is correct when it is in (0, 90, 0) location. But when the line is tilted and rotated in z axis, the topCurrentpoint seems to be revolving around the currentpoint at a certain height. How can i solve this ?

Here is the code i used.

```
  double currentpoint[3];
    currentpoint[0] = sphere_x;
    currentpoint[1] = sphere_y;
    currentpoint[2] = sphere_z;

    double topCurrentpoint[3];
    topCurrentpoint[0] = sphere_x;
    topCurrentpoint[1] = sphere_y;
    topCurrentpoint[2] = sphere_z + (110 * scale_z);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> needleTransform_init = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
    needleTransform_init->Translate(currentpoint[0], currentpoint[1], currentpoint[2]);
    needleTransform_init->RotateX(90);
    needleTransform_init->Translate(-currentpoint[0], -currentpoint[1], -currentpoint[2]);
    needleTransform_init->TransformPoint(topCurrentpoint, topCurrentpoint);

    qDebug()<<" angles before rea"<<roll<<elevation<<azimuth;
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> needleTransform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
    needleTransform->Translate(currentpoint[0], currentpoint[1], currentpoint[2]);
    needleTransform->RotateZ(180+roll); // (180+roll)
    needleTransform->RotateX(elevation); // (elevation)
    needleTransform->RotateY(180-azimuth); // (180-azimuth)
    needleTransform->Translate(-currentpoint[0], -currentpoint[1], -currentpoint[2]);
    needleTransform->TransformPoint(topCurrentpoint, topCurrentpoint);

    vtkNew<vtkLineSource> lineSource;
    lineSource->SetPoint1(currentpoint);
    lineSource->SetPoint2(topCurrentpoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the 180-roll and 180-azimuth that made the errors.

```
needleTransform->RotateZ(azimuth); 
needleTransform->RotateX(elevation); 
needleTransform->RotateY(roll);
```

This is the answer.